# Juju waiting for machine, what it's really doing?

Tags: juju, lxd

Juju is inside  LXD, bootstrapped for local provider, doing `juju deploy kubernetes-core`. It's stuck on something:

```
$ juju status
Model    Controller  Cloud/Region         Version
default  lxd-test    localhost/localhost  2.0.2

App                Version  Status       Scale  Charm              Store       Rev  OS      Notes
easyrsa                     waiting        0/1  easyrsa            jujucharms    7  ubuntu  
etcd               2.2.5    blocked          1  etcd               jujucharms   24  ubuntu  
flannel            0.7.0    blocked          2  flannel            jujucharms   11  ubuntu  
kubernetes-master  1.5.3    maintenance      1  kubernetes-master  jujucharms   12  ubuntu  exposed
kubernetes-worker  1.5.3    waiting          1  kubernetes-worker  jujucharms   14  ubuntu  exposed

Unit                  Workload     Agent       Machine  Public address  Ports  Message
easyrsa/0             waiting      allocating  0/lxd/0                         waiting for machine
etcd/0*               blocked      idle        0        10.135.205.182         Missing relation to certificate authority.
kubernetes-master/0*  maintenance  idle        0        10.135.205.182         Rendering authentication templates.
  flannel/0*          blocked      idle                 10.135.205.182         Waiting for etcd relation.
kubernetes-worker/0*  waiting      idle        1        10.135.205.130         Waiting for kubelet to start.
  flannel/1           blocked      idle                 10.135.205.130         Waiting for etcd relation.

Machine  State    DNS             Inst id        Series  AZ
0        started  10.135.205.182  juju-6eac29-0  xenial  
0/lxd/0  down                     pending        xenial  
1        started  10.135.205.130  juju-6eac29-1  xenial  

Relation      Provides           Consumes           Type
certificates  easyrsa            etcd               regular
certificates  easyrsa            kubernetes-master  regular
certificates  easyrsa            kubernetes-worker  regular
cluster       etcd               etcd               peer
etcd          etcd               flannel            regular
etcd          etcd               kubernetes-master  regular
cni           flannel            kubernetes-master  regular
cni           flannel            kubernetes-worker  regular
cni           kubernetes-master  flannel            subordinate
kube-dns      kubernetes-master  kubernetes-worker  regular
cni           kubernetes-worker  flannel            subordinate
```

What can be done? Are there more precise logs?

Comment: can you share the output of juju status --format yaml ? you can also check juju controller logs for more precise info. To ssh to juju controller, switch to "controller" model

Comment: To switch, run $ juju switch controller and then ssh to juju-controller node by running $ juju ssh 0

Comment: check logs /var/log/juju/

Comment: to ssh back to your current model, run $ juju switch default